# how to find nearest value of each elements in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want to find range between closest value of this elements.
Delta value between elements. And it would be positive number because its modulus.

```
class Element {


double DeltaValue;


double ElementValue;


public Element(double n) {

ElementValue = n;

}

static void Main() {


list<Element> ListElements = new list<Elements>;


ListElements.Add(3);

ListElements.Add(10);

ListElements.Add(43);

ListElements.Add(100);

ListElements.Add(30);

ListElements.Add(140);

for(int i = 0; i < ListElements.Count; i++) { 

ListElements[i].DeltaValue = //and problem is here 


//example as for ListElements[2].DeltaValue will be 13; because 43-30=13;

}
```

//example as for ListElements[2].DeltaValue will be 13; because 43-30=13;

Comment: Have you thought about sorting the array?

Comment: @Sidias-Korrado well no i have never used it before

Answer (score 2):

Just sort the array in increasing order and the smallest difference between the previous and the next element of the current element will solve your problem. Here for last element you can just look at the difference of its previous element.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do it in one line with linq via the following:

```
public static int GetClosestVal(this int[] values, int place)
{
    return values.OrderBy(v => Math.Abs(v - values[place])).ToArray()[1];
}
```

The following outputs `30`

```
var testArray = new [] {3, 10, 43, 100, 30, 140};
Console.Write(testArray.GetClosestVal(2));
```

Basically speaking you sort by the absolute difference between each item and the chosen item, then grab the **second** item in the list since the first will always be the item itself (since n-n=0)

Thus the sorted list should be `[43, 30, 20, 3, 100, 140]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether I understand your question right. If I have, then the following code snippet can help you:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Elements ListElements = new Elements();

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(3);

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(10);

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(43);

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(100);

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(30);

        ListElements.ElementValue.Add(140);


        ListElements.CreateDeltaValues();


        for (int i = 0; i < ListElements.DeltaValue.Count; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ListElement["+i+"]: " + ListElements.DeltaValue[i]);


            //example as for ListElements[2].DeltaValue will be 13; because 43-30=13;

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Elements
{
    public List<double> DeltaValue = new List<double>();
    public List<double> ElementValue = new List<double>();

    public void CreateDeltaValues()
    {
        this.ElementValue.Sort();

        for (int i = 1; i < this.ElementValue.Count; i++)
        {
            var deltaValue = this.ElementValue[i] - this.ElementValue[i-1];
            this.DeltaValue.Add(deltaValue);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a console application, but this code should work also for other app models.

This code generates the following output:

[image]

Comment: Yep of course Sean, but i've just started and not enough repts to upvote ;)

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct. You only must click on the hook under the down and upvote.

Comment: Because you are new, you should make this little tour. It will help you to understand stackoverflow a little better. http://stackoverflow.com/tour and you will earn a litte thing after you make the tour. You only need 3 minutes to make this tour.